# jQuery: Fade out from current opacity

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein, fadeout

I'm fading an object from 0% to 100% on `mouseOver`, and fade back out to 0% on `mouseOut`.

When I do a quick `mouseIn` and `mouseOut`, the effect "jumps" because `mouseOut` is fading out from 100% - and because I do a quick `mouseIn` and `mouseOut`, the fade in doesn't fade all the way to 100%. Maybe it only fades to 25% or 10%.

My question is:
How can I make the fadeout only fading from the specific percentage?

If the `fadeIn` only gets to 20, the `fadeOut` should `fadeOut` from 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try doing:

```
$('#element').animate({opacity:0});
```

...instead of fadeOut().

Comment: If that doesnt work you could try `.stop()` and start the `.fadeOut()` again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your current code looks like, but you'll want to use the jQuery .animate() function:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Here is an example:

```
$('#object').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 1,
  }, 1000, function() {
    //completion code?
  });
});

$('#object').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0,
  }, 1000, function() {
    //completion code??
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery's `.fadeTo()` method](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) which lets you set a target opacity.

```
$('selector').fadeTo('slow', 1);
$('selector').fadeTo('slow', 0);
```

The first argument is the speed, the second is the opacity.

---

If you're using `.hover()` you could do it like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ecUdS/

```
$('selector').hover(function( evt ) {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', evt.type === 'mouseenter' );
});
```

This [uses `.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the animation if it is running.

Then [because `.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) will fire for both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, I added a test where if it is a `mouseenter`, it will send `true` (which will equate to `1`). Otherwise it sends `false` or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue once upon a time.  You can't really use jQuery's animate functions because it always wants to complete the animation.  So I wrote my own function for it.. hope this helps (also I wasn't expecting to share this someday, so it has been written to be suited to how I was using it):

```
//Custom fade effects.
//Similar to jQuery's fadeIn & fadeOut
//Except that it doesn't queue animations, and can cut the animation short at anytime
//Highly useful for quickly hovering over elements and desiring the fade effects to be cut on hover in/out.

function fade(elem, interval) 
{
    if(!(elem instanceof $)) {
        elem = $(elem);
    }

    if(elem.is(':not(:visible)')) {
        elem.css('opacity', '0').show();
    }

    elem.css('opacity', function() { 
            var current = $(this).data('fadeLevel') || 0;

            //normalize - accounts for tiny descrepancies in parsing
            if(current < 0) { current = 0; } 
            if(current > 1) { current = 1; } 

            $(this).data('fadeLevel', current + interval)

            return $(this).data('fadeLevel');
        });

    if(elem.data('fadeLevel') < 0 || elem.data('fadeLevel') > 1 ) {
        clearTimeout(elem.data('fadeTimer'));
    }
}

function fadeIn(elem) { fadeTo(elem, 0.04, 0); }
function fadeOut(elem) { fadeTo(elem, -0.04, 1); }
function fadeTo(elem, interval, level) {
    if(!$(elem).data('itemOpen')) {
        clearTimeout($(elem).data('fadeTimer'));
        $(elem).data('fadeLevel', level).data('fadeTimer', setInterval(function() { fade(elem, interval) }, 30));
    }
}
```

Examples

http://jsfiddle.net/3AxHb/